# CMake is successful, but make fails when linking

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake, homebrew, gstreamer

I am trying to compile my project on macOS with CMake. I have gstreamer installed via brew and I can access the include directory. For example this is the include directoy for gstreamer:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.16.2/include/gstreamer-1.0/
```

When running `cmake` with following `CMakeLists.txt` everything runs successfully, but `make` fails when I trying to link with following error:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable multiviewer
ld: library not found for -lgstreamer-1.0
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(application)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5WebSockets REQUIRED)

# Required for GStreamer
find_package(PkgConfig)

# Look for GStreamer installation
pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)

add_executable(application
        main.cpp qml.qrc server.cpp server.h
        ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS} client.cpp client.h)

# Qt5
target_link_libraries(application Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::WebSockets)

# GStreamer
target_include_directories(application PUBLIC ${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(application PUBLIC ${GST_CFLAGS})
target_link_libraries(application ${GST_LIBRARIES})
```

Here are the packages I've installed:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install gstreamer
brew install gst-plugins-base
brew install gst-plugins-good
brew install gst-plugins-bad
brew install gst-plugins-ugly
brew install gst-libav
```

Output of `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0`:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.2.1/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.16.2/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.4/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.4/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.43/include
```

Output of `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0`:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.16.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.4/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Do I need something else to install or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the contents of the `GST_LIBRARIES` variable? It seems the GStreamer library is not being linked. Try `message("GST_LIBRARIES: ${GST_LIBRARIES}")`

Comment: @squareskittles The output is: `GST_LIBRARIES: gstreamer-1.0;gobject-2.0;glib-2.0;intl`

Comment: Ok, this issue is that the *full* path to the library is not known by the compiler. You may have better luck using the `GST_LINK_LIBRARIES` variable instead, if it's populated correctly.

Comment: @squareskittles Thank you! That's the solution. You may want to write an answer so that I can accept it for future lost souls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

```
ld: library not found for -lgstreamer-1.0
```

indicates that the library `gstreamer-1.0` was passed to the linker, but the linker doesn't know where to find it (likely because it does not reside in the typical system paths). It is up to CMake to provide the **full** path to the GST libraries. From the [`pkg_check_modules`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) documentation, here are some of the library-related variables populated for a generic package `XXX`:

> - `<XXX>_LIBRARIES`:
>     only the libraries (without the ‘-l’)
> - `<XXX>_LINK_LIBRARIES`:
>     the libraries and their absolute paths
> - `<XXX>_LIBRARY_DIRS`:
>     the paths of the libraries (without the ‘-L’)

The `GST_LIBRARIES` variable will only list the library names (`gstreamer-1.0;gobject-2.0;glib-2.0;intl`), but in this case, we need to provide the library paths as well. So, change the `target_link_libraries()` call to use `GST_LINK_LIBRARIES`:

```
target_link_libraries(application PUBLIC ${GST_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```